# unity 3d- Large Score numbers turn into exponents C#

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, converters, exponent

I've come across a problem where my score numbers have turn into exponents.
What I want to know is, how do you convert large floats and int exponent numbers into regular long numbers?

Comment: You'll need to post some code examples or more details on what is happening. You haven't included enough info for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably just a matter of the default number formatting when converting ints and floats to string.  To specify a particular conversion method, try using `string.Format()` with the appropriate format string.  [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s some info on number format strings for use with `string.Format`.  By default, .NET appears to give you what you'd get with "General."  (You probably want "Fixed-point.")

Sample code:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("my long number is {0:F}", 1234567891234567891.23));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help.

Here is a solution for those who use unity3d C#:
Select a format style from here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
*Thankyou adv12 for the link*

before:

```
public GUIText score;

void update()
{
score.text = "Score:" + clicks;
}
```

After:

```
public GUIText score;

void Update ()
{
score.text = "Score:" + clicks.ToString ("f");
}
```